# How to find the percentage difference(rise or drop) in pandas when using dataset?(column wise)

Tags: python

Below is my dataset, when I try to run the code, I get the following errors, but the code is correct. I want to find the difference between the years 2019 and 2020, how much has raised or dropped.

Dataset used:
[image]

Errors:

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Please show the code and what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
df['difference'] = df['Amount for year 2019'].sub(df['Amount for year 2020'])
```

Comment: that's awesome! but how do I enter as it in percentage value like, for example showing 100 to 110 is 10% rise in the difference coloumn?

Comment: and also the negative sign isn't showing up for some values. For example, the Annual maintenance contract of FY19 is 16,125 and FY20 is 80,199 so the answer should be -64,074. Is there any way to produce that or else just showing the percentage increase and decrease?

Comment: @JeremMoses Edited my answer should work now